# Steam is not opening after installation

Tags: 18.04, steam

I get the following:

> Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again.

Here is the complete error output:

```
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Verifying installation...
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Unable to read and verify install manifest 
/home/USER/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Verification complete
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Downloading Update...
[2019-10-08 16:43:58] Checking for available update...
[2019-10-08 16:43:59] Download failed: http error 403 (client- 
download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2019-10-08 16:43:59] Download failed: http error 403 
(media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2019-10-08 16:43:59] Failing manifest download with http error 403 
(media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12)
[2019-10-08 16:43:59] Error: Download failed: http error 403
[2019-10-08 16:43:59] Error: Steam needs to be online to update.     
Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2019-10-08 16:44:03] Shutdown
threadtools.cpp (3283) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of 
worker thread 'Thread(0x0x578609a0/0x0xf43ccb'
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? Are you behind proxy? Are you able to open steam's site on a browser?

Comment: @Kulfy Yes i have access to internet I can open steam in browser.

Comment: It seems that your steam version is 3 years old. Please run `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb; sudo dpkg -i steam-latest.deb` and then try again opening steam.

Comment: I tried to run the above command `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb; sudo dpkg -i steam-latest.deb` but it throws this error **dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'steam-latest.deb': No such file or directory**

Comment: In the same directory where you ran that command, try `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb`. If `wget` succeeded, you have a downloaded file in that location. I expect that file to be called `steam.deb` rather than `steam-latest.deb`, because `steam.deb` is in the URL, and because the file I get when I run that `wget` command is `steam.deb`. (If you've already deleted the downloaded file, just run `wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb` again before running `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb`.) If there are further errors, you can **[edit]** your question to include them in full. @Kulfy

Comment: Strange though. When I downloaded I got steam-latest.deb when I tried from Firefox. @EliahKagan

Comment: @Kulfy I *believe* this is because support for `Content-Disposition` headers is still considered experimental in `wget` and disabled by default. It can be enabled [with the `--content-disposition` option](https://superuser.com/a/301051). When I ran `wget --content-disposition https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb`, the downloaded file was `steam_latest.deb`. Without `--content-disposition`, I got `steam.deb`. Firefox also gave me `steam_latest.deb`. (OTOH, if you actually got `steam-latest.deb`, with a hyphen rather than an underscore, I'm not sure why that would happen.)

Answer (score 1):

As documented at [Steam doesn't see network in ubuntu 16.10](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661) on GitHub, people have had this problem for a while. **It can often, though not always, be solved by installing the `libnss-resolve:i386` package**. Note that this is the `libnss-resolve` package for the i386 architecture, even if you're using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu (which is the amd64 architecture).

To install that, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnss-resolve:i386
```

Then try running Steam again.

*Thanks to [Sweeze](https://github.com/sweeze) for [finding this solution](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661#issuecomment-253963646)! (But note that it [doesn't work for everyone](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661#issuecomment-442139702).)*

Comment: The workaround mentioned on [GitHub's page](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661) and this answer addresses `http error 0` but in the question it seems OP is having `http error 403`. I'm not sure if installing this package would work.

Comment: I tried this already but still it is showing the same error ! :(

Comment: @Santhosh After you got [that other error while trying to install the new version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179480/steam-is-not-opening-after-installation#comment1970313_1179480), did you try [installing with `sudo dpkg -i steam.deb` as described in that comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179480/steam-is-not-opening-after-installation#comment1970357_1179480)? I recommend that you edit your question to update it with information about that.